# Ajax load with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal [please click to see demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/NpaKbb) and my modal has been opening automatically and closing automatically too and I need one more thing is ajax content and I guess it can be with load function I found some function but I couldn't apply it because I don't want to loaded clicking by link I have to loaded automatically after my modal open

I have two attribute `data-open` and `data-close` to open and close automatically my modal

```js
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(e){
    $('#AniPopup').modal('show');
  }, parseInt($('#AniPopup').attr('data-open')) * 1000);
  setTimeout(function(e){
    $('#AniPopup').modal('hide');
  }, parseInt($('#AniPopup').attr('data-close')) * 1000);
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="modal fade" id="AniPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AniPopupLabel" aria-hidden="true"  data-close="1000" data-open="2" data-src="https://www.youtube.com">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Popup Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call call your ajax request into this code..

```
$(function(){
          setTimeout(function(e){
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  data: {},
                  url: [Server URL],
                  success: function(response){
                      // do anything with response you want
                      $('#AniPopup').modal('show');
                      hidePopUp(); // you have to initiate hidepopup to ensure you timeout is after ajax complete not before as ajax are async call.
                  }
              })
          }, parseInt($('#AniPopup').attr('data-open')) * 1000);

            function hidePopUp(){
              setTimeout(function(e){
                $('#AniPopup').modal('hide');
              }, parseInt($('#AniPopup').attr('data-close')) * 1000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yeah it's good  but doesn't work I set a web adress to url may be that is why doesn't work..and is there any way to get url from attribute ? like `data-open` or `data-close`

Comment: and it must call in `.modal-body` my ajax content

Comment: web address is not your url, you need to have get response JSON from your server..

Comment: so your response will write into .modal-body class may be like `$('.modal-body').html([your response here..])` before your `$('#AniPopup').modal('show');` line

Comment: okey I get from my server `test.html` but my modal hasn't opened

Comment: could you post your URL? .html can never be the url

Comment: yes my url is html what kind of type that I have to get ?

Comment: `.html` is webpage and not URL, probably you first need to have look how the make ajax call to server as per backend you are using. Once you get hand on it then apply my solution, it will work for you.

Comment: I have applied your solution already but I had seen before the url was .html for example https://jsfiddle.net/ednon5d1/ if yousee `remoteControl.html` is html but if is not ajax..

Comment: what you mean by ajax content here? which backend your are using to get data into ajax?

Comment: see my updated fiddle of your fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/AbhinavWase/ednon5d1/1624/

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap provides you with these options

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...probably make an ajax call and get data 
})

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution I use in every project.

Root javascript so I can open modal on every page:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).data('href');
    var modalId = '#'+$(this).prop('href').split('#')[1];
    if (url.indexOf('#') === 0) {
    } else {
        $(modalId+' div.modal-content').html(
            $(modalId+' div.modal-dialog img#ajax-loader').clone().removeClass('hidden')
        );
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $(modalId+' div.modal-content').html(data) ;
        });
    }
});
```

Then you need this HTML in your template, I include it in base template so it is available on every page:

```
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="display: none" id="ajax-modals">
    <!-- Fix if datepicker is used in modal -->
    <style>
        .datepicker{z-index:1151 !important;}
    </style>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <img src="/img/select2-spinner.gif" id="ajax-loader" class="hidden" style="margin: 20px auto; display: block;"/>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- comes from ajax -->

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

To trigger the modal you need links like this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#ajax-modals" data-href="/ajax-url" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" >Load Modal with AJAX content</a>
```

And at least, this is the content your AJAX-Controller should return:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        ×
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">
        Modal title
    </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    Modal body goes here

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close window
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){

        //you can do some javascript here

    });
</script>
```